# Swift - UIAppearance Class

Tags: ios, swift, uiappearance

I have label in my Storyboard connected to my View Controller via an IBOutlet

I have extended UILabel as below

```
extension UILabel {
    func winnerLabel() -> UILabel {
        let winnerLabel = UILabel()
        winnerLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
        winnerLabel.textAlignment = .left

        return winnerLabel
    }
}
```

In my view controller I would like to set the label from the storyboard to have the same appearance as the winnerLabel.

What's the best way to set the style properties of the label I have an outlet for to the the winnerLabel?

I can do them individually, ie textColor = winnerLabel.text color, but think there must be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don’t use a function. Use a UILabel subclass that initializes itself with the desired features, and make the label in the storyboard an instance of that subclass.

Comment: For an example see http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch07.html#_additional_initialization_of_nib_based_instances

Comment: And https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/61f0c753a080040e4a74b912e6c18dd97fe8bcaa/bk1ch07p339additionalConfiguration/bk1ch07p339additionalConfiguration/RedButton.swift

Answer (score 1):

You can assign this class in IB

```
class CustomLabel: UILabel {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        shared()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        shared()
    }
    func shared() {
       // all the layout code from above
       self.textColor = .red
       self.textAlignment = .left
    }
}
```

//

[image]

//

For programmatically

```
let lbl = CustomLabel(frame:CGRect(x:0,y:20,width:200,height:200))
```

Comment: How would you set the class programmatically for a label that is already created? I don't think it's possible

Comment: that's great for Storyboard, how about changing the class through code?